# how do I change a parameter value in a parameter file dynamically in Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: shell, unix, informatica, winscp

Parameter files have a variable `$$envFile` that have been hardcoded as DEV, UAT or PROD ($$envFile = DEV for Dev environment, $$envFile = UAT for QA environment, etc. ). We need to make this customized so that if some param file is copied to QA or prod environment, it automatically updates the values as DEV or UAT for respective environment.

How to achieve this via Informatica PC or by using a shell script?

Comment: Not sure how you set things up, but i would say, if  you are using some scheduler, define a global parameter envFile there and change its value in each environment. Or else use a shell script to change after migration.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question of using Informatica. Here we're talking about deployment to different environments, which should be handled by CI/CD tool - NOT Informatica.

Set up a Jenkins job, Git Action, Azure Pipeline - or whatever is available in your organization.